# Path por defecto para entrada y salida de archivos y ficheros en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rutas, ide

mi pregunta no irá acompañada de código puesto que se trata de la configuración que pueda tener el proyecto o el eclipse en sí.

Pongamos que por ejemplo utilizamos la class `File` para crear con el método `.createFile()` un nuevo fichero... Sin especificar la ruta, este fichero de normal se guardaría dentro del proyecto, no obstante con MÍ eclipse se guarda dentro de la carpeta de instalación del propio eclipse.

En resumen, el path por defecto de entrada y salida de ficheros que tengo en mi eclipse es la porpia carpeta de instalación de eclipse y necesito configurarlo para que el Path por defecto de entrada y salida de fichero o archivos sea la propia raíz del proyecto.

He estado mirando bastante información por internet, pero no he sacado nada en claro, y no he podido modificar esta ruta de por defecto.

Alguien con experiencia en Eclipse podría ayudarme a modificar esta propiedad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando lanzas una aplicación desde Eclipse, se usa la configuración ya existente para dicha aplicación o, si no existe (es la primera vez que intentas ejecutarla), se crea una configuración automáticamente para la aplicación. Puedes ir al menú `Run`, seleccionar `Run configurations...` y en esa pantalla podrás consultar y editar la configuración de ejecución de tu aplicación. Entre otras cosas, puedes definir el ***Working Path***:

Comment: muchas gracias, mañana en la oficina lo intento